laravel model pages not communicating properly
Working on a client project, hit a setback.
Laravel is reading

"Call to undefined relationship [service_item] on model [App\Models\Service]".

It's simply trying to read data from two different tables in the same database.
I've used this method on a different project under differently named variables, had no problem then but now I don't know what I've done wrong.
ServiceController
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Models\Service;

class ServiceController extends Controller
{
    public function getService()
    {
        $services = Service::with('service_item:resource,resource_id')->get();
        return view('pages.service', compact('services'));
    }
}

Service Model
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Service extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function service()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Service::class);
    }
}

Service_Item model
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Service_Item extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function serviceItem()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Service::class);
    }
}


https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many Re-read how relations are formed. Your Service class should have a serviceItems method, not a service method. Service_Item class has the same mistake. And both relations point to a Service::class? That's wrong too

The way you defined your model relationship is not correct.Also you should add $fillable property on the models for mass assignment.

Looking at your models relationships in both your models are wrong.
Assuming service_items table has service_id as foreign key
Service Model should be
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Service extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function serviceItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Service_Item::class);
    }
}

While Service_Item Model should be
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Service_Item extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function service()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Service::class);
    }
}

And in controller
$services = Service::with('service_items:resource,resource_id')->get();

Also recommend to switch name of Service_Item Model to ServiceItem
